# Installing multiple versions of sun java

Tags: installation, java, jdk

I have a need to maintain different versions of a certain product written in java, and uses sun's jdk to build. Some older versions of the product need an older jdk (1.5) and the newer ones need jdk 1.6. So, my question is how can I install (and maintain) multiple versions of sun's jdk. I don't want openjdk, icedtea or whatever else, but different versions of sun's jdk itself.

I ask this as I've seen I have the commands `python`, `python2.6` accessible. If I install another python version, I get it as `python2.7` although the `python` command doesn't point to it. This is exactly the kind of setup I need with java. But anything close also works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. you can.  Check this article. http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2007/04/2-jvm-on-one-linux-box.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing a self-contained installation of jdk 1.5 to be used exactly whenever needed. I am not adding it to alternatives though.

Comment: I attempted to use this method for Saucy (13.10), and it appears there is not a `sun-java6-jdk` package available under the backport libraries for this newer version of Ubuntu.